# Why does express app not recognize dotenv file

Tags: javascript, node.js, dotenv

I installed **dotenv**, created a .env file and wrote `PORT = 5000` into it, but for some reason it says that the value in it is undefiend. What is the problem?

File location:

```
└── src
     ├── index.js
     └── .env
```

```
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');

const PORT = process.env.PORT;
const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send("Test");
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`${PORT} server has been started`);
});
```

Comment: You should use require('dotenv').config('./src') instead, if your env file is not located in the root.

Answer (score 0):

`.env` file must be located inside the root directory (on the same level that `package.json` is located). Not in `src`